# sap.m.Table behaviour change

Tags: sapui5

For reasons I am trying to understand the behaviour of sap.m.Table has change in 1.85+

Below from the [release notes](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/eeb5bd913fe448598e0449050143027a.html).

> sap.m.Table  If the sum of the width of all columns in a table is less
> than the available space for the whole table, we now render a
> placeholder column to occupy the remaining unused space. This feature
> is enabled by default.

However I am unable to locate the property that would restore the behaviour of sap.m.Table to its prior behaviour. Given I have production sites in UI5 its frustrating as this has effectively changed the appearance (in a detrimental way) for some pages of my UI5 SPAs.
Is it true that implicit in the above would be the need to "inject" the currently unlocated parameter in all of my sap.m.Tables and set it to whatever the value would need to be.

Help on this would be appreciated.

While I could solve this by fixing (making static) the runtime version that is not a long term solution for me (I use the published CDN) - it does represent my current workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I found this line in the docs:

> If the width property is defined for all columns (and not the expected
> "auto" value), then the sap.m.Table control renders a dummy column
> which occupies the remaining width of the control. This only happens
> if there are no columns in the pop-in area. Note: The dummy column is
> rendered only if the fixedLayout property is enabled.

Comment: Tx - set one column's width value to auto and this appears to have prevented the calc taking place and rendering the meaningless space. Thank you

Comment: see my feedback from openui5 team below

Answer (score 1):

PER OPENUI5 Team: (they are reverting)

The change to the sap.m.Table was intentional, we introduce a dummy column, when all columns in the table have a predefined width.
To avoid seeing the dummy column in your table, you should **leave the most important column's width empty or set it to auto **, the same is also documented below:
https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/6f778a805bc3453dbb66e246d8271839
Non-the-less, we introduced this behavior by default in version 1.85, but with 1.86, we have reverted this behavior and the dummy column would render only when the fixedLayout="Strict" is applied to the sap.m.Table control. For more information:
https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.Table#methods/getFixedLayout
So in the latest nightly built release you would see the sap.m.Table is rendered as it was prior to 1.85. You can test your app with with src below:
https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/sap-ui-core.js